# How to loop in ObservableList<Tab> for JavaFX

Tags: java, for-loop, javafx, foreach, iterator

I am working in JavaFX and I have this `ObservableList<Tab>`. Can you tell me how I can loop and get the content of a content of the list? maybe something like this:

```
ObservableList<Tab>

for (....){

tabPane.getTabs().add(i);

)
```

Comment: what is `Tab`? which `list` ?

Comment: insufficient information, provide a more detailed view of your question....

Comment: Is this the JFace databinding ObservableList type, or something else?

Comment: Like any `Iterable` object, just need to read few things about Java basics :)

Answer (score 7):

Java 8 supports `.forEach()`

```
ObservableList<Tab> tabs = ...
tabs.forEach((tab) -> { 
    System.out.println("Stuff with "+tab);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

```
ObservableList<Tab> obList;

for(Tab tab : obList) {
  tab.doWhateverYouWant(); // "tab" is the reference to current Tab in this loop.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean a for each loop in which you do something with every element that's in the list?

```
ObservableList<Tab> myList = ...;

for (Tab tabPane : myList){

    // Do whatever you want to do with tabPane
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `ListIterator<Tab>` like this:

```
ObservableList<Tab> list = ...;
Tab currentTab;
for(ListIterator<Tab> iterator = list.listIterator(); iterator.hasNext(); currentTab = iterator.next()) {
    // use currentTab here
}
```

or even an enhanced for loop:

```
for(Tab currentTab : list) {
    // use currentTab here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely there will be a get method to expose the Tabs. For example:

```
ObservableList<Tab> list = ...;
for (Tab tab: list.get()) {
    // do something
}
```